# Loop through classes, and obtain their list item's innerHTML jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

There's an HTML page with 3 elements containing a class of ".list". Those ".list" elements have "li" elements in them, and in those "li" elements, there is text. I'd like to loop through all of "li" elements, and push their text to an array, with jQuery.

**This is what I have so far:**

```
var arr = [];

$(".list").each(function() {
  this.children("li").each(function() {
    arr.push(this.innerHTML);
  });
});
```

However, I'm getting an error back from the console.

**Error:**

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

What am I doing wrong, and how can I fix it?

Comment: It's a good idea to include the error message in your questions, if for no other reason than the fact that taking time to read and type them often helps with understanding what the message is trying to tell you.

Comment: @Pointy Good point... Pointy. (no pun intended) I've edited the post to include the error message.

Comment: Right - well that message is notoriously confusing, but it means that `this.children` is `undefined` - that is, that there's no `children` property. Because your code tried to make a function call via that `undefined` value, you get that error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value of `this` in your `.each()` loop will be a reference to an element, not a jQuery object. Thus:

```
$(".list").each(function() {
  $(this).children("li").each(function() {
    arr.push(this.innerHTML);
  });
});
```

That is, `$(this).children` instead of `this.children`.

Note that you could avoid the outer `.each()` (not that there's anything terrible about it):

```
$(".list > li").each(function() {
  arr.push(this.innerHTML);
});
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks Pointy! The extra, and more succinct code really helps too. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try following code. This will work for you

```
var arr = []; 
var div = $(".list");
div.each(function() { 
    div.children("li").each(function() { 
           arr.push(this.innerHTML); 
    }); 
});

console.log(arr);
```